# SDL2 and OpenGL functions with two windows

Tags: opengl, sdl

I am trying to make one application with two windows with SDL2. To make draw process faster and capable to run 3d animations I am using OpenGL. But when I open second window, how can I said to OpenGL (gl functions) to draw in second window?
I searched into libsdl wiki but cant find anything.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are looking for the [`SDL_GL_MakeCurrent`](http://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_GL_MakeCurrent) function.

> Use this function to set up an OpenGL context for rendering into an OpenGL window.

Example:

```
SDL_GL_MakeCurrent(window, gl_context);
// OpenGL functions will draw to window
// ...
SDL_GL_MakeCurrent(window2, gl_context);
// OpenGL functions will draw to window2
```

Comment: Presumably you'd have to be updating the viewport as well?  At least if the windows are of different dimensions?  Maybe that's a reason to have a second context instead of sharing one?

Comment: I believe it's more like `SDL_GL_MakeCurrent(window1,context1); /* window1/context1 stuff */ SDL_GL_MakeCurrent(window2,context2); /* window2/context2 stuff */`, where you are specifying which window+context pair the GL calls refer to, and each window is associated with its own GL context.